# Regex php repeat character error

Tags: php, mysql, regex, parsing, migration

I'm tried parse MySQL dump for auto creating migrations.

Drop database parsed with:

```
preg_match_all('/DROP TABLE.+`.+`(.+|.?);/', $this->contents, $this->dropTableBlock);
```

But create table query return false and empty array:

```
preg_match_all('/CREATE TABLE.+`.+`.+\(.+\).+(ENGINE=.+)?.+(DEFAULT CHARSET=[.]{1,5});/is', $this->contents, $this->createTableBlock);
```

On regex101.com that's matches need strings:
https://regex101.com/r/eD8wI5/1

Tell me please, why preg_match_all finds nothing?

Comment: You can further improve performance [like this at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pD0xL0/1) (also to match engine).

Comment: It isn't a job for regex. You should use a SQL parser, for example this one: https://github.com/greenlion/PHP-SQL-Parser

Comment: Isn't `(.+|.?)` the same as `(.*)` But even that does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `[]` around the dot fix it.

```
preg_match_all('/CREATE TABLE.+`.+`.+\(.+\).+(ENGINE=.+)?.+(DEFAULT CHARSET=.{1,5});/is', $content, $matches);
```

Comment: But yes, I agree with other comments. You should not use that to migrate databases. There are tools build especially for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
\s*DROP\s+DATABASE\s+((`.+`|\w+)\.)(`.+`|\w+)\s+;
```

Notes

- Handles leading/trailing spaces
- Treats newlines and tables as whitespace
- handles optional backtics
- handles `dbname.tablename` syntax
- \w does not handle all the possible characters for db/table names